# Fill missing elements for table in xml with xsl

Tags: xslt, cells, xmltable

I have an xml like the snippet below. The "all-attribs" elements are the total number of unique columns for a table. The "attrib" elements are what will become the columns for each row. What I want to do is to use the "all-attribs" to fill out the missing elements..

I'm not very good at this, but I've really tried my best to solve it.
I managed to create the correct number of cells and match the ones that should be populated, but I don't know how to pull in the data in the "name" element since I'm using  a for-each loop that sets the context to "all-attribs" (I hope you understand what I mean).

XML:

```
<root>
    <all-attribs>
        <attrib>first</attrib>
        <attrib>second</attrib>
        <attrib>third</attrib>
        <attrib>fourth</attrib>
        <attrib>fifth</attrib>
    </all-attribs>
    <items>
        <item>
            <attrib handle="first">
                <name>First</name>
            </attrib>
            <attrib handle="third">
                <name>Third</name>
            </attrib>
            <attrib handle="fifth">
                <name>Fifth</name>
            </attrib>
        </item>
        <item>
            <attrib handle="second">
                <name>Second</name>
            </attrib>
            <attrib handle="fourth">
                <name>Fourth</name>
            </attrib>
        </item>
        <item>
            <attrib handle="first">
                <name>First</name>
            </attrib>
            <attrib handle="fifth">
                <name>Fifth</name>
            </attrib>
        </item>
    </items>
</root>
```

Desired result:

```
<root>
    <items>
        <item>
            <attrib>First</attrib>
            <attrib/>
            <attrib>Third</attrib>
            <attrib/>
            <attrib>Fifth</attrib>
        </item>
        <item>
            <attrib/>
            <attrib>Second</attrib>
            <attrib/>
            <attrib>Fourth</attrib>
            <attrib/>
        </item>
        <item>
            <attrib>First</attrib>
            <attrib/>
            <attrib/>
            <attrib/>
            <attrib>Fifth</attrib>
        </item>
    </items>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="item" select="." />
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/all-attribs/attrib">
            <attrib>
                <xsl:value-of select="$item/attrib[@handle=current()]/name" />
            </attrib>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```